# Convert System.Drawing.Bitmap to MLImage in ML.NET 2.0

Tags: c#, ml.net

I have an application that uses ML.NET 1.7 and I am trying to convert to ML 2.0. The new version uses MLImage instead of Bitmap but in my application the images are already used and precessed as bitmaps.

I first changed my Input class from:

```
    public class Input
    {
        [ImageType(ImageSettings.imageHeight, ImageSettings.imageWidth)]
        public Bitmap Image { get; set; }
    }
```

to

```
    public class Input
    {
        [ImageType(ImageSettings.imageHeight, ImageSettings.imageWidth)]
        public MLImage Image { get; set; }
    }
```

But I am having trouble changing my current calling method:

```
    Prediction prediction = predictionEngine.Predict(new Input { Image = myBitmap });
```

I would need to convert myBitmap to MLImage. I tried streaming it and calling it from MLImage like this as I already have the image in memory as a Bitmap:

```
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    myBitmap.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Bmp);
    Prediction prediction = predictionEngine.Predict(new Input { Image = 
    MLImage.CreateFromStream(imageStream)});
```

but does not seem to work.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I created a function to do the conversion, but I am not convinced this would be the most efficient way of doing this.

```
        public static MLImage bitmapToMLImage(Bitmap bitmap)
        {
            var width = bitmap.Width;
            var height = bitmap.Height;

            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
            BitmapData bmpData = bitmap.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bitmap.PixelFormat);
            var length = bmpData.Stride * height;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[length];
            Marshal.Copy(bmpData.Scan0, bytes, 0, length);
            bitmap.UnlockBits(bmpData);

            return MLImage.CreateFromPixels(width, height, MLPixelFormat.Rgba32, bytes);
        }
```

Any comments? By the way an easier way would be to save to an external file and then create MLIMage from the file but that would be even more inefficient.

Edit:

Finally found how to do it using memorystreams:

```
        MemoryStream ms = new();
        bitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```